# Intermittent Shape Mismatch Error in TensorFlow Model with Optuna Hyperparameter Tuning

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a ml model for time series prediction. The model is built using TensorFlow and TensorFlow Probability, and I am using Optuna for hyperparameter tuning. The model uses a custom loss function and is trained on a dataset with specific shapes for X and Y.

The issue I am facing is an intermittent shape mismatch error that occurs sporadically and is hard to reproduce. The error typically looks like this:

`Incompatible shapes: [267] vs. [0]`
or
`Incompatible shapes: [0] vs. [32,24]`

a simplified version of the implementation:

```
# ... (import statements and other setup)
def objective(trial: optuna.Trial):
    # ... (data loading and preprocessing)
    inputs = keras.Input(X.shape[1])
    # ... (model layers)
    outputs = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
        lambda t: tfd.JohnsonSU(
            loc=t[..., :24],
            scale=1e-3 + 3 * tf.math.softplus(t[..., 24:48]),
            tailweight=1 + 3 * tf.math.softplus(t[..., 48:72]),
            skewness=t[..., 72:],
        )
    )(linear)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 1e-5, 1e-1, log=True)),
        loss=lambda y, rv_y: -rv_y.log_prob(y),
        metrics="mae",
    )
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1500, validation_data=(Xf, Yf), callbacks=callbacks, batch_size=128, verbose=False)

metrics = model.evaluate(Xf, Yf)
metrics_sub.append(metrics[0])
```

An example of a failed model:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 266)]                0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 batch_normalization (Batch  (None, 266)                  1064      ['input_1[0][0]']             
 Normalization)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)               (None, 773)                  206391    ['batch_normalization[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 954)                  738396    ['dense[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 24)                   22920     ['dense_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 24)                   22920     ['dense_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 24)                   22920     ['dense_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 24)                   22920     ['dense_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 96)                   0         ['dense_2[0][0]',             
                                                                     'dense_3[0][0]',             
                                                                     'dense_4[0][0]',             
                                                                     'dense_5[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 distribution_lambda (Distr  ((None, 24),                 0         ['concatenate[0][0]']         
 ibutionLambda)               (None, 24))
```

I have tried debugging by logging shapes and checking for NaN or Inf values in the data, but everything seems fine. The error is hard to reproduce, even when using the same hyperparameters that led to the error in a previous Optuna trial.

Any insights into why this might be happening and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.